# Gluon Single view Client:Build

Tags: netbeans, client, pom.xml, gluon

this is probably something simple: I have created a single-view Gluon app in Netbeans.  It runs if I execute the goal javaFx:run, but fails when I run the client:build goal.  I have not added anything to the application but am trying to gain an understanding of the basics.
If my pom specifies a property like it does <client.plugin.version>0.1.38</client.plugin.version>.  Shouldn't maven automatically pull in all the dependencies associated with using that property?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.testgluon_4_2_2021</groupId>
    <artifactId>testgluon_4_2_2021</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>testGluon_4_2_2021</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>16</javafx.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.11</attach.version>
        <client.plugin.version>0.1.38</client.plugin.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.5</javafx.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>com.testgluon_4_2_2021.TestGluon_4_2_2021</mainClassName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${client.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${client.target}</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <client.target>host</client.target>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>display</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>ios</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>android</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

and here is the error that I am getting

```
Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.38:compile (default-cli) on project testgluon_4_2_2021: Error: Cannot run program "cl" (in directory "C:\Users\X\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testGluon_4_2_2021\target\client\x86_64-windows\gvm\testGluon_4_2_2021"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1
```

What do I need to fix in order to execute a client:build?

Comment: Are you running from an x64 terminal? See docs: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_windows

Comment: No, I was not using the correct terminal.  I have x64 Visual studio prompt running and it's giving me this                                                                                            [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'client' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Darre\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Make sure you cd into the project folder where the pom file is located

Comment: @JoséPereda I am having the same problem trying to execute gluonfx:build on the "SingleView" gluon example in the documentation. I am using Eclipse (2021-06, 4.20.0). The error about not being able to find "CL" occurs both from within eclipse run configuration launch and from ADMIN cmd prompt from the project directory. Do you have any additional advice or links or should I start a new StackOverflow question? What, btw, is CL and why is it being called? (Is it a VisualStudio utility? Do I have to install VisualStudio to run Gluon Mobile?)

Comment: @PhilFreihofner See https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_create_run_a_native_image_of_the_application_3 (the important note for Windows and use of terminals). CL (`cl.exe`) is a compiler see (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160)

Comment: OK. So installing Visual Studio really is a requirement to run this software on Windows. Holy smokes. Thank you for clarifying.